# how to create a new record in form datasource from x++

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, axapta

In form `Journal Voucher` (AR>Journal> PaymentJournal> clicking button`Lines`). I want to create a new record from x++ code.

I have seen few methods in the form viz create(), initvalue(), ledgerJournalEngine_custPayment... etc which are called when we press `ctrl+n` . How we could use these methods through x++ code to create a record using standard functionality.

plz help.

Comment: You should extend the base functionality properly with the ledgerjournal classes.  Can you provide more details?  Do you want to create a single or multiple lines immediately upon clicking "lines"?  Or do you want to create a journal & lines from an X++ class or something?  There is an entire form framework (LedgerJournalForm*) and a table framework (LedgerJournalT*), and the posting engine.  So if you want form functionality, it'd make sense to use the form framework, while if you are trying to just create lines on an existing journal for example via some other function, it wouldn't.

Comment: what i am trying is after clicking on `Lines` and opening a new form `Journal Voucher` added a customized button `Function>settlement using cust group` after clicking that form `CustTransOpen` opens based on cust group selelcted. Now based on the marking I have to sum up `amounts` based on `AccountNum` and create records accordingly in form `JournalVoucher`. I am just stuck up with the last part.

Comment: I follow somewhat. Please explain more. `Func>Settlement` is what you're trying to copy it sounds like, but it takes 1 line, then settles it based on marked records. You want to do `Func>SettleUseCustGrp` (custom) from the lines screen (F\LedgerJournalTransCustPaym) and just automatically create multiple transaction lines in the journal? The difference being `Func>Settlement` uses the LedgerJournalTrans record, while you will not. Do I have this right?

Comment: absolutely.. I will just select the `Settlement cust group` so the new settlement form based on `cust Group` will open and after i mark/unmark, amounts are summed up based on AccountNum and create single/multiple records accordingly in form `JournalVoucher`.. I have added the above code(attached picture)in `close()` event for form `custOpenTrans`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you elaborated, I thought you were trying to create your own custom form extending the journal functionality.  If you're just trying to create a tool, you can just create a new `Settlement Using Cust Group` button.  In the clicked event, call your transaction marking form or whatever you do to get the transactions you want to use.  Then put something like this in it:

```
void clicked()
{
    ;

    element.lock();

    super();

    // Put your code here to call the open transaction editing code

    // CREATE THIS CUSTOM METHOD on C\LedgerJournalEngine_CustPayment\settleTransCustGroup
    ledgerJournalEngine.settleTransCustGroup(ledgerJournalTable);

    ledgerJournalTrans_ds.active();
    ledgerJournalTrans_ds.reread();
    ledgerJournalTrans_ds.executeQuery();

    //recalculate balances
    ledgerJournalEngine.newJournalActive(ledgerJournalTable, true);
    element.firstField();
    element.unLock();
}
```

Then in the new method you created, which I named `settleTransCustGroup`, you can loop over your records in the `testLedgerJournalSpecTrans` modeling off of something similar to this (custom method created on the engine class):

```
void settleTransCustGroup(LedgerJournalTable    _ledgerJournalTable)
{
    LedgerJournalTrans      ledgerJournalTrans;
    ;
    // Turn this stuff into a loop and default whatever else you need
    ledgerJournalTrans.clear();
    ledgerJournalTrans.initValue();
    ledgerJournalTrans.AccountNum = '100003';
    ledgerJournalTrans.AmountCurCredit = 10;
    this.initValue(ledgerJournalTrans);
    ledgerJournalTrans.insert();
    this.write(ledgerJournalTrans);

    ledgerJournalTrans.clear();
    ledgerJournalTrans.initValue();
    ledgerJournalTrans.AccountNum = '100005';
    ledgerJournalTrans.AmountCurCredit = 15;
    this.initValue(ledgerJournalTrans);
    ledgerJournalTrans.insert();
    this.write(ledgerJournalTrans);
}
```

Comment: actually i thought of initiating the NumberSeq for Voucher and also Once the record are created in `LedgerJournalTrans` record C1, C2, C3 are created... I also need to keep account of what are the record was marked earlier for a particular customer e.g. C1

Comment: I can't understand what you're saying.  I'm not going to code your entire project for you...

Answer (score 1):

Generally, your X++ code would look something like this:

```
static void InsertRecord(Args _args)
{
    LedgerJournalTrans  ledgerJournalTrans;
    ;

    ledgerJournalTrans.AccountNum = "10000";
    ledgerJournalTrans.AmountCurCredit = 50.64;
    ledgerJournalTrans.AccountType = LedgerJournalACType::Ledger;
    ledgerJournalTrans.insert();
}
```

You can replace the fields and values as needed. If any fields are missing, the error will display in the infolog (for example, if you were to run the above, you will get a "Currency code must be specified" error), so be sure all required fields are addressed.

In most cases, you can also call `ledgerJournalTrans.initValue();` before assigning your values to pre-populate the record with default AX values. I believe this will be the same as what you see when you use Ctrl + N on the form. In the above example, doing so will cause the Currency Code to be filled in, and the record to be saved correctly (at least on our system).

Comment: i need to add a record just like standard functionality (assigning number sequence, initializing the ledgerJournalEngine_custPayment class etc).

Comment: You can get number sequences as outlined at http://dynamics-ax-dev.blogspot.com/2010/04/obtaining-next-number-sequence-via-x.html. As for the other functionality, you could just duplicate it into your own class and execute it from there. I would assume most of it would be in the common codebase already through (on the table or a class the form references). It shouldn't be difficult to mimic that functionality. From my experience, however, just calling the straight .insert() method will allow the record to go through normal AX processes. I suggest testing it in a test environment to see.

Comment: one problem i am facing is how to pass the datasource instance from x++ as is expected in `ledgerJournalEngine.formMethodDataSourceCreatePost();`

Comment: I'm not seeing that requirement in my version of that method in my system, but the name implies it should be call from a form, not from code. Are you just trying to create a journal record line, or are you trying to post the journal as well? I would suggest to play with it in a test environment. Try just inserting the record, and see if that accomplishes what you need.

Comment: i am using Ax2009 its the method initvalue where the Num seq and other default values are initialized `void initValue()
{
    ;
    super();

    ledgerJournalEngine.formMethodDataSourceCreatePost();
    ledgerJournalEngine.initValue(ledgerJournalTrans);
}`

Comment: That looks like it is only asking for a LedgerJournalTrans table buffer, possibly just the record that is being inserted. You should be able to accomplish the same task by calling those methods after the `ledgerJournalTrans.initValue();` and passing `ledgerJournalTrans` into the `ledgerJournalEngine`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magical way of calling standard funcionality out of the frameworks quoted here on other comments. For each Ledger Type (Accounting, Inventory, Orders, Payments, ...), the way of creating and initializing lines is different and you have to work on this specific way if you want the journal to post properly.

There are a lot of examples on google of X++ code that inserts journal transactions for almost every type of them. It's not easy, but at least it's always almost the same code and it can be easilly reused.